# Must I create an instance of Long to send a Long as a parameter?

Tags: java, oop, memory, casting

I'm trying to add an element to a LinkedHashMap. each entry in the LHM is a key and a class called Page.

I wrote this code:

```
public void addPage(Page<byte[]> addPage)
{
    if(numOfPages < initialCapacity) // Checks that there is room 
    {
        pages.put(new java.lang.Long(addPage.hashCode()), addPage);
        numOfPages++;
    }
}
```

It seems to work and doesn't give any errors.

But I don't understand why:

```
public void addPage(Page<byte[]> addPage)
{
    if(numOfPages < initialCapacity) // Checks that there is room 
    {
        pages.put(java.lang.Long(addPage.hashCode()), addPage);
        numOfPages++;
    }
}
```

doesn't work. Why must I actually create a new instance of `Long` instead of just cast the int returned from hashCode to Long? Seems very wasteful.

Edit - the class Page:

```
public class Page<T> 
{
    private T content;
    private java.lang.Long pageId;

    public Page(java.lang.Long pageId, T content)
    {
        this.pageId = pageId;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public java.lang.Long getPageId()
    {
        return pageId;
    }

    public void setPageId(java.lang.Long pageId)
    {
        this.pageId = pageId;
    }

    public T getContent()
    {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(T content)
    {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public boolean equals(Page<T> page)
    {
        if(this.pageId == page.getPageId())
            return true;
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: `pages.put(java.lang.Long(addPage.hashCode()), addPage);` is syntactically wrong. Is this just a copy&paste error when you created the post here or have you actually tried it with this line?

Comment: hashCode() is usually an `int` value and it is not guaranteed to be unique, you will get duplicates. It's not that wasteful when you compare the code of a Map Entry, or the size of the value you are using. It's unlikely to make much of a difference. More of a problem is that your hashCode() are highly likely to repeat at around 60K entries, long before you have to worry about some wasted memory.

Comment: I see. That is indeed a big problem. Is there a better way to hash then?

Comment: @OriaGruber The usual way is to use the `Page` instances themselves as keys. Is there a reason why you can't do this?

Comment: @PaulBoddington yes. pages has to be of type private java.util.Map<java.lang.Long,Page<byte[]>>. So the key has to be Long.

Comment: I edited the original post, you can now see page class.

Comment: @OriaGruber I assume you're meant to use `pageId` values as keys.

Comment: @PaulBoddington That seems odd. Each page has its Id as a member. Why do I need to save it again in the LHM? If I do that, I'm basically storing the same information twice.

Comment: @OriaGruber What List? Do you mean Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Casting" here is going to just hide the object creation from you, so it's equally efficient.

The way I'd tend to write this would be to write `(long) addPage.hashCode()`, which will get compiled into autoboxing which will (in almost all cases) allocate a new `Long` object anyway.

Alternately, you could write `Long.valueOf(addPage.hashCode())` which will make the boxing explicit but will cache small `hashCode` values.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.Long(addPage.hashCode())
```

is not valid syntax. If the key type of the `map` is `Long`, you have to do

```
pages.put((long) addPage.hashCode(), addPage);
```

because an `int` will not be implicitly converted to a `Long`.

Even though it may not look like it, this code *does* create a new instance of `Long`, because it implicitly boxes the `long` to a new `Long` (unless the `hashCode` is between `-128` and `127` as these `Long`s are cached).

> Seems very wasteful.

Yes, it is. This is because at present, primitives cannot be used as generic types. I believe this will change in Java 10.